# cache size, set associative and direct mapping

Tags: caching, mapping, line

Considering a machine with a byte-addressable main memory of 256 Kbytes and a block size of 8 bytes. With a set associative mapped cache consisting of 32 lines divided into 2-line sets.

1. The address 110101010101011010 is stored in the 11th set, what other
   memory address would be stored in the same set in the cache. If this
   byte was stored in the cache in the clock cycle immediately
   following the address for the previous one then would it overwrite
   that byte?
2. If direct mapping had been used instead of set associative then the
   main memory address would be divided up differently. How would it be
   divided up?
3. In direct mapping into which line would the byte 110101010101011010
   with the following address be stored.
4. What other memory address would be stored into the same line in the cache? If this byte was stored in the cache in the clock cycle immediately after the previous address then would it overwrite that byte?

Explanations as to why would be extremely helpful as i'm trying to understand how to work these out for further understanding.